# Nunit .Net Core Parallel Tests

Tags: nunit

This was mentioned by Charlie Poole :

If you are running .NET Core tests, you are using the NUnit portable framework build, which does not support parallel execution. The attribute is still accepted so that you can switch to different platform builds without changing the code

Does any one know if this is still the case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is still the case as of NUnit 3.8.1. Even though the Portable version of the framework has been replaced by a .NET Standard version, parallel test execution has not been enabled yet.

Parallel execution is enabled in NUnit by the `PARALLEL` conditional compilation which isn't enabled in the .NET Standard projects yet.

**Update** NUnit 3.10.1 has been released which re-enables most of the parallel features when you use .NET Standard/Core 2.0+.

Comment: Hi Rob ,Thank you so much for the quick response really appreciate it.