# How to perform global setup/teardown in xUnit and run tests in parallel?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, initialization, nunit, xunit

Here is what I want to achieve with xUnit:

1. Run initialization code.
2. Run tests in parallel.
3. Perform teardown.

I have tried [CollectionDefinition]/[Collection]/ICollectionFixture
approach [described here](https://xunit.github.io/docs/running-tests-in-parallel.html) but it has disabled the parallel execution, which is critical for me.

Are there any way to run tests in parallel and be able to write global setup/tear-down code in xUnit?

If it is not possible with xUnit, does NUnit or MSUnit support this scenario?

Comment: See also answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53143426/193178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit supports this scenario. For global setup, create a class in one of your root namespaces and add the [[SetupFixture]](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute) attribute to it. Then add a [[OneTimeSetUp]](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeSetUp-Attribute) method to that class. This method will get run once for all tests in that namespace and in child namespaces. This allows you to have additional namespace specific onetime setups.

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class MySetUpClass
{
  [OneTimeSetUp]
  public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
  {
    // ...
  }

  [OneTimeTearDown]
  public void RunAfterAnyTests()
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then to run your tests in parallel, add the [[Parallelizable]](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parallelizable-Attribute) attribute at the assembly level with the `ParallelScope.All`. If you have tests that should not be run in parallel with others, you can use the `NonParallelizable` attribute at lower levels.

`[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]`

Running test methods in parallel in NUnit is supported in NUnit 3.7 and later. Prior to that, it only supported running test classes in parallel. I would recommend starting any project with the most recent version of NUnit to take advantages of bug fixes, new features and improvements.

Comment: Thant you, Rob! Is it possible to configure setup method for a group of test classes (collections in terms of xUnit)? Like ICollectionFixture is doing it for xUnit, but tests within collection must run in parallel.

Comment: Yes, the setup fixture in the code example is for a namespace, so you should group tests that need the same setup in the same namespace (or in child namespaces) and create setup fixtures for each namespace that needs them.

Comment: I just realized that parallel execution is not supported in NUnit on .NET Core. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526999/nunit-net-core-parallel-tests

Comment: Parallel execution for. NET Core will be in the next release. Watch this space 

Answer (score -2):

A somewhat basic solution would be static class with a static constructor and subscribing to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit` event.

```
public static class StaticFixture
{
    static StaticFixture()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += (o, e) => Dispose();

        // Initialization code here
    }

    private static void Dispose()
    {
        // Teardown code here
    }
}
```

There's no guarantee when the static constructor gets called though, other than at or before first use.